# Please help me understand operator overloading = in linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I have a structure like this -

```
struct IntNode
{
    int data;                   
    IntNode * next;         
};
```

and in the class -

```
    class NodeSLList {
    private:``
        IntNode *head, *tail;
//some other functions
    }
```

I have an object `list1` which contains the linked list with few nodes. I have to create another linked list `list2` from `list1`. 
How do I achieve this using the function-

```
NodeSLList & operator=(NodeSLList &list){}
```

I am not able to undestand how to access `list2` inside operator `=` function as I will be passing `list1` inside like-

```
list2=list1;
```

How do I access `list2`??

Comment: with the help of 'this' pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `this` pointer points to exiting class you are operating on, thus, `this->head` or simply `head` is the member of old list which is you want to change, and `newList.head` is the member of new list that you have to assign.

```
NodeSLList & operator=(NodeSLList &newList)
{
        //Check if there is something to free?
        if(head != NULL) //this->head != NULL
        {                    
                //free head
        } 
        //Assign new one
        head = newList.head; //this->head = newList.head;
        //Other stuff if any
        return this;
}
```

Comment: `//this.head = list.head;` `this` is a pointer, so one uses the `->` operator instead.

Comment: so this->head and head are both same?? means both are referring to list2??

Comment: @ChiranthBs, yes, `this` is optional, `head` and `this->head` are same, in your case, `this` points to list2, which is left side of `=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`this` would be a pointer to the left operand, which is `list2` in your case. To get list2 itself, simply dereference it using the dereferencing operator `*`. ie `*this`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `*this`.

Anyway. please don't implement your own linked list. There already is `std::list`, or if you need a doubly linked list `std::deque`. You'd need a lot of effort to make your code as high quality as the standard library, let alone define an interface, that is equally well thought out.

So if this is four your school, write your own linked list. We all did that. It is a good way to practice programming with pointers. But please resist the temptation to do something like that later in production code. I have seen it too often, and it is slow and inefficient most of the time, and often pretty buggy as well.

Answer (score 0):

The function (operator) `NodeSLList & operator=(NodeSLList &list)` is called a [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator). It does not create new objects but assigns to them. So for your first question

> I have to create another linked list list2 from list1. How do I
>   achieve this using the function...

The answer is; you don't. First you create a new object `list2` and then you can assign to it. The following code will first call the default constructor and then the copy assignment operator:

```
NodeSLList list2;
list2 = list1;
```

So actually `list2 = list1;` is a shorthand for

```
list2.operator=(list1);
```

Perhaps this makes it more clear that the function `operator=` is used on an existing object, and as all other answers has pointed out, you access this object by `*this`.

As an aside, if you wrote `NodeSLList list2 = list1;`, you would be calling the [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), which is an other story...